# What happens if I change the Mealy state machine for the 1011 bit sequence detection?

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines, sequence-detector

I want to detect the 1011 bit sequence in my Mealy state machine.
The correct graph is shown below:

[image]

What would happen if I stay at state `S3` instead of going to `S1` when I get a '1'?

I think that the output will be:

```
input  = 101111111
output = 000111111
```

Until `S3`, I have detected 101, so when another 1 will come, i.e., 101, is it going to go back on state 101 and outputting "1" every time?
Am I thinking right?

Comment: you need an S4 state, that is reached when you input 1011 .... S3 goes to S4 instead of S1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you **change** the state machine such that it remains in state `S3` when the next input is 1, the output will stay at 1.

To demonstrate this, you can run this [Verilog simulation on EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/DrSC).  It shows an input data stream similar to what you describe, but you can change the input sequence to whatever you want.

Here is the simulation output:

```
          10 input=0 output=0
          20 input=0 output=0
          30 input=0 output=0
          40 input=1 output=0
          50 input=0 output=0
          60 input=1 output=0
          70 input=1 output=1
          80 input=1 output=1
          90 input=1 output=1
         100 input=1 output=1
         110 input=1 output=1
         120 input=1 output=1
         130 input=0 output=0
         140 input=0 output=0
```